# How to specify facebook graph API version while using devise and omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm using devise and omniauth-facebook authentication in my rails 4 application.

Facebook has moved on to v2.x graph API. (deadline for api migration is April 30, 2015).

During authentication, facebook's login dialog show the following message

```
"You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x
v1.0 will be deprecated on April 30, 2015
Learn how to upgrade"
```

I figured this is because omniauth-facebook/devise right now uses facebook graph api v1.x.

How do I configure it to point to v2.x ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution, hope it helps someone as well

The link is https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/152

Solution is to configure provider for omniauth-facebook in initializer file as:

```
 provider :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET'],
    :scope => 'email,read_stream',
    :client_options => {
      :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0',
      :authorize_url => "https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth"
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it to work or at least I don't see any change, because I still receive the "username" field from the FB API response, and this field is suposed to be removed on API versions >2.0. Any clue on how can I check it for sure if it is making calls to the v2.0 or not?